# Referencing an entire property in multiple serverless files - [object Object] does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

One of the biggest challenges that I've faced using serverless is in deploying AWS Lambda functions in a micro-service fashion (Each lambda individually - I've already tried individual packages, Webpack, and so on...).

I'm currently breaking my serverless app into multiple sub-serverless files and I'm trying to reference a main config serverless one. I'd like to inherit entire object trees so I don't have to be retyping them one by one (In addition, if there's a change, I can propagate it throughout all the lambdas).

Here's my current structure:

```
| serverless.yml
| lambda/
|       /planning
|                index.ts
|                serverless.yml
|       /generator
|                index.ts
|                serverless.yml
|       /createStudents
|                index.ts
|                serverless.yml
```

Content of the **main** serverless file (Omitted for brevity):

```
## https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/
service: backend-appsync

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-2
  ## https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/
  ## https://serverless.com/blog/abcs-of-iam-permissions/
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:BatchGetItem"
        - "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
        - "dynamodb:ConditionCheckItem"
        - "dynamodb:GetItem"
        - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
        - "dynamodb:PutItem"
        - "dynamodb:Query"
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:747936726382:table/SchonDB"
```

I'd like to read the entire provider object and insert it into the individual `serverless.yml` file.

Example: `/lambda/planning/serverless.yml`

```
service: "planning"
provider: ${file(../../serverless.yml):provider}
functions:
  planning:
    handler: ./index.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-planning
    description: Handles the Planning of every teacher.
    memorySize: 128
```

I get the following error:

> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
>
> The specified provider "[object Object]" does not exist.
>       Get Support --------------------------------------------
>        Docs:          docs.serverless.com
>        Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
>        Issues:        forum.serverless.com
>
> Your Environment Information ---------------------------
>        Operating System:          win32
>        Node Version:              12.14.1
>        Framework Version:         1.61.2
>        Plugin Version:            3.2.7
>        SDK Version:               2.2.1
>        Components Core Version:   1.1.2
>        Components CLI Version:    1.4.0

I thought I could reference the entire property. Is this possible? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks :)

Comment: While not the same, I ended up ditching serverless and going with Pulumi instead https://www.pulumi.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serverless goes nuts when files are imported from outside the project directory.
To solve this problem, you can now use projectDir:

```yaml
service: "planning"
projectDir: ../..
provider: ${file(../../serverless.yml):provider}
functions:
  planning:
    handler: ./index.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-planning
    description: Handles the Planning of every teacher.
    memorySize: 128
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've moved away from Serverless to Pulumi for managing my infrastructure, and everything has been way smoother. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer as no answer has been placed and it seems to solve the issue!